Issue with Reading from Local JSON File in React, Works Fine with API
I'm relatively new to React and I'm encountering an issue with reading from a local JSON file. Strangely, when I attempt to read data from an API, everything works perfectly fine. Could someone please help me understand what might be causing this discrepancy and how to resolve it?
Below, I've provided my code snippet along with a corresponding StackBlitz example for reference.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wrni65?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FProductListing.jsx,src%2Fdata%2Fphotos.json
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import '../App.css';
import Photos from '../data/photos.json';
// import './App.css';
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'; // Assuming you're using React Router

const ProductListing = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [filteredProducts, setFilteredProducts] = useState([]); // State for search results
  const navigate = useNavigate(); // Import useNavigate hook

  const [cart, setCart] = useState(() => {
    // Load existing cart from localStorage
    const storedCart = localStorage.getItem('cart');
    return storedCart ? JSON.parse(storedCart) : [];
  });

  const addToCart = (product) => {
    const newCart = [...cart, product];
    setCart(newCart);
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(newCart)); // Store updated cart
  };

  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const productsPerPage = 50;
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState(''); // Search state

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProducts = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('./data/photos.json');
        setProducts(response.data);
        setFilteredProducts(response.data); // Initialize filtered products
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error);
      }
    };
    fetchProducts();
  }, []); // Calculate indices for slicing the array

  // Handle search input changes
  const handleSearchChange = (event) => {
    setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
  };

  // Perform search filtering when the search term changes
  useEffect(() => {
    const newFilteredProducts = products.filter((product) =>
      product.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
    );
    setFilteredProducts(newFilteredProducts);
    setCurrentPage(1); // Reset pagination when search changes
  }, [searchTerm, products]);

  // Calculations for pagination (using filteredProducts)
  const indexOfLastProduct = currentPage * productsPerPage;
  const indexOfFirstProduct = indexOfLastProduct - productsPerPage;
  const currentProducts = filteredProducts.slice(
    indexOfFirstProduct,
    indexOfLastProduct
  );

  // const indexOfLastProduct = currentPage * productsPerPage;
  // const indexOfFirstProduct = indexOfLastProduct - productsPerPage;
  // const currentProducts = products.slice(
  //   indexOfFirstProduct,
  //   indexOfLastProduct
  // );

  const handlePageChange = (pageNumber) => {
    setCurrentPage(pageNumber);
  };

  const renderPagination = () => {
    const pageNumbers = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(products.length / productsPerPage); i++) {
      pageNumbers.push(i);
    }
    return (
      <nav>
            
        <ul className="pagination">
               
          {pageNumbers.map((number) => (
            <li
              key={number}
              className={
                currentPage === number ? 'page-item active' : 'page-item'
              }
            >
                     
              <a
                onClick={() => handlePageChange(number)}
                href="#"
                className="page-link"
              >
                        {number}
                       
              </a>
                    
            </li>
          ))}
              
        </ul>
           
      </nav>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="product-container">
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search..."
        value={searchTerm}
        onChange={handleSearchChange}
        className="search-input"
      />
         
      {error ? (
        <p className="error-message">Error fetching products</p>
      ) : (
        <>
                     {/* Added for pagination container */}
               
          <div className="product-grid">
                  
            {currentProducts.map((product) => (
              <div className="product-item" key={product.id}>
                {/*         {product.id} */}
                        
                <img
                  src={product.thumbnailUrl}
                  alt={product.title}
                  style={{ width: '50px', marginRight: '10px' }}
                  className="product-image"
                  onClick={() => navigate(`/reviews/${product.id}`)} // Navigate to review page
                />
                <p className="product-id">{product.id}</p>
                <button onClick={() => addToCart(product)}>Add to Cart</button>
                       
              </div>
            ))}
                 
          </div>
               {renderPagination()}
          <Link to="/checkout" className="checkout-button">
            Go to Checkout
          </Link>
              
        </>
      )}
        
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductListing;


Are you using the file, or are you still making an API request?  You import the JSON data from the project here:
import Photos from '../data/photos.json';

But you never use it.  Instead, you try to fetch it via AJAX here:
const response = await axios.get('./data/photos.json');

However, this file isn't hosted as part of the resulting output of the application.  So the server is returning HTML instead.  (Perhaps a 404 page, perhaps the main page of the application, etc.)
Since you're already importing the data you need, there's no need to make an AJAX request to get that same data.  You can remove the useEffect for fetchProducts entirely and just initialize the state values to the imported data:
const [products, setProducts] = useState(Photos);
const [filteredProducts, setFilteredProducts] = useState(Photos);


To further @David's point of removing useEffect -- This Read is an excellent explanation as to why useEffect is overused and can cause undue overhead in your App.

@Zak can you please update in fiddle....it so confusing

@Ram01 -- No need for that.  Take David's advice.  Simply remove the entire useEffect  block and use Photos --  You're already importing it.

@David thanks for your response, what I thought was if I use axios and read my local json data later I can directly replace the path with actual URL. Is there any way I can achieve using axios or is there any other package to support this type of functionalities . Providing my updated stackblitz here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wrni65?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FProductListing.jsx,src%2Fdata%2Fphotos.json

@Ram01: If you don't want to import the data but instead want to make an AJAX request to fetch the data then you'd (1) put the code back to the way you had it, (2) remove the import for that JSON file since you don't want to use it, and (3) put the JSON file somewhere that it would be served as part of the resulting website.  I'm not familiar with how to do that on Stackblitz specifically.  But basically the published application on your server would need that file.  Wherever you serve the website, copy the file to a location there.

@David can you help me withis question too --->  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78421045/trouble-moving-items-between-columns-in-react-using-react-beautiful-dnd

@David can you help me with this question too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78421045/trouble-moving-items-between-columns-in-react-using-react-beautiful-dnd
